# Trying to understand the relationship between the normal form and the extensive form

Tags: game-theory

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Prove that if in a 2X2 normal-form game all payoff vectors are
> distinct, then up to relabeling of actions **the game has exactly two
> extensive forms in which every decision node has at least two actions
> and there are no moves of nature.** Prove that this is true for any
> finite two-player normal-form game in which all payoff vectors are
> distinct (with at least two strategies for each player).

Can someone please help me understand the answer? Here is the answer:

[image]

I struggle to understand the case (i). What does it mean by "changing the action corresponding to the information set $I_2$ for player 1"? Can someone please draw a game tree to illustrate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following extensive form:
[image]

Here, player $1$ has two information sets and case (i) holds. Take the strategy profile $(a,ce)$, which leads to terminal node $t$. But changing player $1$'s action at information set $I_2$ form $e$ to $f$ results in the strategy profile $(a,cf)$, which still leads to terminal node $t$. Thus, in the normal form, one has $u(a,ce)=u(a,cf)=(1,2)$, contradicting the assumption that all payoff vectors are distinct.